# obtener valor de fila de checks seleccionados

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo una tabla html y en cada registro le coloco un checkbox ¿Como podria hacer para que cuando seleccione algunos registros con el checkbox me obtenga los datos de la fila para enviarlos a traves de un formulario?,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
 //cada elemento seleccionado
 alert($(this).val());
});
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento1" value="1"/></td>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>bbb</td>
<td>ccc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento2" value="2"/></td>
<td>ddd</td>
<td>eee</td>
<td>fff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento3" value="3"/></td>
<td>ggg</td>
<td>hhh</td>
<td>iii</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento4" value="4"/></td>
<td>jjj</td>
<td>kkk</td>
<td>lll</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento5" value="5"/></td>
<td>mmm</td>
<td>nnn</td>
<td>ooo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento6" value="6"/></td>
<td>ppp</td>
<td>qqq</td>
<td>rrr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento7" value="7"/></td>
<td>sss</td>
<td>ttt</td>
<td>uuu</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento8" value="8"/></td>
<td>vvv</td>
<td>www</td>
<td>xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento9" value="9"/></td>
<td>yyy</td>
<td>zzz</td>
<td>AAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento10" value="10"/></td>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>CCC</td>
<td>DDD</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="seleccionar" onclick=""/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

En el ejemplo anterior solo obtengo el valor del check pero no el de toda la fila ¿Que podria hacer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asumo que los valores que quieres obtener son los textos que están en cada uno de los `td` de la fila del checkbox, para lo cual buscaremos en el DOM el `td` "padre" del checkbox seleccionado y luego encontraremos los otros `td` adyacentes:

```js
  // para cada checkbox "chequeado"
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){

    // buscamos el td más cercano en el DOM hacia "arriba"
    // luego encontramos los td adyacentes a este
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(){

      // obtenemos el texto del td 
      console.log($(this).text());
    });
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento1" value="1"/></td>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>bbb</td>
<td>ccc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento2" value="2" checked="checked" /></td>
<td>ddd</td>
<td>eee</td>
<td>fff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento3" value="3" checked="checked"/></td>
<td>ggg</td>
<td>hhh</td>
<td>iii</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento4" value="4"/></td>
<td>jjj</td>
<td>kkk</td>
<td>lll</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento5" value="5"/></td>
<td>mmm</td>
<td>nnn</td>
<td>ooo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento6" value="6"/></td>
<td>ppp</td>
<td>qqq</td>
<td>rrr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento7" value="7"/></td>
<td>sss</td>
<td>ttt</td>
<td>uuu</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento8" value="8"/></td>
<td>vvv</td>
<td>www</td>
<td>xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento9" value="9"/></td>
<td>yyy</td>
<td>zzz</td>
<td>AAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento10" value="10"/></td>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>CCC</td>
<td>DDD</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="seleccionar" onclick=""/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Modificación para obtener los valores seleccionados como una cadena, separados por espacios:

```js
    // para cada checkbox "chequeado"
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
    var result = [];
    var i = 0;
    
    // buscamos el td más cercano en el DOM hacia "arriba"
    // luego encontramos los td adyacentes a este
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(){

      // obtenemos el texto del td 
      result[i] = $(this).text();
      ++i;
    });

    console.log(result.join(' '));
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento1" value="1"/></td>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>bbb</td>
<td>ccc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento2" value="2" checked="checked" /></td>
<td>ddd</td>
<td>eee</td>
<td>fff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento3" value="3" checked="checked"/></td>
<td>ggg</td>
<td>hhh</td>
<td>iii</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento4" value="4"/></td>
<td>jjj</td>
<td>kkk</td>
<td>lll</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento5" value="5"/></td>
<td>mmm</td>
<td>nnn</td>
<td>ooo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento6" value="6"/></td>
<td>ppp</td>
<td>qqq</td>
<td>rrr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento7" value="7"/></td>
<td>sss</td>
<td>ttt</td>
<td>uuu</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento8" value="8"/></td>
<td>vvv</td>
<td>www</td>
<td>xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento9" value="9"/></td>
<td>yyy</td>
<td>zzz</td>
<td>AAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento10" value="10"/></td>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>CCC</td>
<td>DDD</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="seleccionar" onclick=""/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Modificación (de nuevo), para obtener una sola cadena con todos los valores seleccionados:

```js
  var result = [];
  var i = 0;
  // para cada checkbox "chequeado"
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
    
    // buscamos el td más cercano en el DOM hacia "arriba"
    // luego encontramos los td adyacentes a este
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(){

      // obtenemos el texto del td 
      result[i] = $(this).text();
      ++i;
    });
  });

  console.log(result.join(' '));
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento1" value="1"/></td>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>bbb</td>
<td>ccc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento2" value="2" checked="checked" /></td>
<td>ddd</td>
<td>eee</td>
<td>fff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento3" value="3" checked="checked"/></td>
<td>ggg</td>
<td>hhh</td>
<td>iii</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento4" value="4"/></td>
<td>jjj</td>
<td>kkk</td>
<td>lll</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento5" value="5"/></td>
<td>mmm</td>
<td>nnn</td>
<td>ooo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento6" value="6"/></td>
<td>ppp</td>
<td>qqq</td>
<td>rrr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento7" value="7"/></td>
<td>sss</td>
<td>ttt</td>
<td>uuu</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento8" value="8"/></td>
<td>vvv</td>
<td>www</td>
<td>xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento9" value="9"/></td>
<td>yyy</td>
<td>zzz</td>
<td>AAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento10" value="10"/></td>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>CCC</td>
<td>DDD</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="seleccionar" onclick=""/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: si, es correcto son los valores que estan en los td del check seleccionado

Comment: Puedes probar mi respuesta entonces.

Comment: como podria hacer para que fuera una sola cadena y no valor x valor en cada iteracion del each?

Comment: una cadena de que tipo? dame un ejemplo

Comment: de los valores de la tabla "aaa bbb ccc" si selecciona el ckeck 1 o si es el 2 "ddd eee fff"

Comment: Mira la modificación que hice.

Comment: Como podria hacer un arreglo para que se vayan almacenando los valores de cada each y mostrarlos todos al final

Comment: Mira la nueva modificación que hice.

Comment: Gracias bro es lo que necesitaba saludos

Answer (score 1):

Con tu código como tal al principio no mostrará nada, supongo que lo haces con una función, lo único que modifique a tu código es el `alert`.

Te explico que hace, El elemento `this` corresponde al `check` seleccionado:

- Ahora, como estás en un elemento que no tiene hermanos, por decirlo así, habrá que subir un nivel con `parent()`
- Ahora tenemos *hermanos* con el padre del elemento seleccionado, aquí aun no podemos acceder a los elementos hermanos, por eso habrá que subir otro nivel de padre
- Después del `parent()` debes buscar el elemento con `.find('td')`
- En este nivel ya podemos acceder a todos los elementos `<td>` con los cuales podemos acceder con `.eq(0)`, `.eq(1)`, etc. antes de `html()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
 //cada elemento seleccionado
 console.log($(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq(1).html());
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().html());
   console.log($(this).parent().parent().text());

});
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento1" value="1" checked/></td>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>bbb</td>
<td>ccc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento2" value="2"/></td>
<td>ddd</td>
<td>eee</td>
<td>fff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento3" value="3"/></td>
<td>ggg</td>
<td>hhh</td>
<td>iii</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento4" value="4"/></td>
<td>jjj</td>
<td>kkk</td>
<td>lll</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento5" value="5"/></td>
<td>mmm</td>
<td>nnn</td>
<td>ooo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento6" value="6"/></td>
<td>ppp</td>
<td>qqq</td>
<td>rrr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento7" value="7"/></td>
<td>sss</td>
<td>ttt</td>
<td>uuu</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento8" value="8"/></td>
<td>vvv</td>
<td>www</td>
<td>xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento9" value="9"/></td>
<td>yyy</td>
<td>zzz</td>
<td>AAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="elemento10" value="10"/></td>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>CCC</td>
<td>DDD</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="seleccionar" onclick=""/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: si coloco eq(1) antes de html me genera undefined y si coloco eq(1) en lugar de html me trae [object object]

Comment: ya encontre como accesar, no se si es correcto, despues de los dos parent le coloque find("td"), depues eq(1) y despues html(), $(this).parent().parent().find("td").eq(2).html()

Comment: Si así, se me olvido mencionar eso disculpa, igual si solo quieres obtener los valores de los otros `td` después del `parent()` puedes poner `.text()` y obtendrás los valores de los `td` a excepción del `check`

Comment: ¿Como podria hacer un solo envio de todos los valores de los checkbox seleccionados?, es que necesito todos los valores y no fila x fila, como ocurre en el ejemplo que me proporcionaste todo dependiendo de los check que se seleccionen, seria como ir almacenando en una variable o arreglo todos los valores de cada iteracion del each pero no se como hacerlo y al final ya enviar esa variable o arreglo