# Selección de Filas de una serie de tablas con un checkbox

Tags: javascript, mvc, razor

Ire al grano, tengo la siguiente vista en razor con un modelo cargado desde el metodo del controlador haciendo uso de la base de datos:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Modelos.Candidates>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Candidates";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

//Tab con botones para mostrar los divs donde se encuentran las tablas

<b> <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px">Seleccion de candidatos</p></b>
<div class="tab">
<button id="btn1" onclick="openCandidate(this)" class="tablinks">Governor</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="openCandidate(this)" class="tablinks">Mayor</button>
<button id="btn3" onclick="openCandidate(this)" class="tablinks">President</button>
</div>

//Uso de Html.Beginform para mandarle las filas al metodo de "CandidatesValidation" con el boton

@using (Html.BeginForm("CandidatesValidation", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
//Div con la tabla de los Gobernadores.
<div id="type1" class="tabcontent" style="display:block" name="Governor">
    <table id="table1" class="responsive-table-input-matrix">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Seleccion</th>
                <th>Candidato</th>
                <th>Partido</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if (item.PositionId == 2)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CandidateName)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
//Div con la tabla de los Alcaldes.
<div id="type2" class="tabcontent" name="Mayor">
    <table id="table2" class="responsive-table-input-matrix">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Seleccion</th>
                <th>Candidato</th>
                <th>Partido</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if (item.PositionId == 3)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CandidateName)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
//Div con la tabla de los Presidentes.
<div id="type3" class="tabcontent" name="President">
    <table id="table3" class="responsive-table-input-matrix">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Seleccion</th>
                <th>Candidato</th>
                <th>Partido</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if (item.PositionId == 1)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CandidateName)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
//Boton para confirmar los candidatos elegidos apartir de los checkbox
<center><button type="submit" class="btn container1">Next</button></center>
<br>
<br>
<br>
}
```

Mi duda es, como le haría para obtener las filas con los checkbox que se encuentren checkeados de cada una de las tablas, y esas filas mandarlas al método de [HttpPost] con el cual haría una validación posterior con dichos elementos.

Tengo el siguiente código de una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18297/obtener-valor-de-fila-de-checks-seleccionadosA) de aquí mismo creo de una función de javascript que lo que hace es, básicamente lo que pido pero no de varias tablas en distintos div si no solo de una tabla y creo que en el ejemplo del blog viene sin div:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
        var result = [];
        var i = 0;

        $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function () {
            result[i] = $(this).text();
            ++i;
        });

        return result.join(' ');
    });
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar, pido disculpas si no fui muy claro, de antemano muchísimas gracias por la atención!!

Comment: Ese código javascript te va a obtener todos los checkboxes que estén checked de todas tus tablas. ¿Es eso lo que quieres o sólo de una tabla?

Comment: Esque lo he probado y no ha funcionado tal vez me he equivocado en la implementacion de la vista o el boton, de todas maneras gracias por la respuesta!!

Comment: Perdón que no me he explicado, lo que quiero es que me obtenga las filas de los checkbox que estén chequeados y al final me las mande al método del controlador [HttpPost]

Comment: ¿Y te ha dado algún error?

Comment: En la consola de la pagina me dice que esta undefined y no me imprime nada si le pongo console.log(result.split(' ')); en lugar de return, me dice lo siguiente al momento de darle inspect y en el apartado de la consola:

Comment: Me aparece eso: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, igual si uso $(document).ready(); o solo uso $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each();

Comment: Eso es porque no has importado la librería de Jquery.

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> es esta? esta en una carpeta del proyecto de ahi que la direccion este asi